# How to queue the collection of js files into one in a webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

For example i have 3 files in my global app.js

```
require('../libraries/file1');
require('../libraries/file2');
require('../libraries/file3');
```

when webpack compiling, app.js have queue of file2, file1, file3.
How to queue the collection of js files into one in a webpack?
How to configurate webpack.config?
I need to run files in my queue. thanks

Comment: i have http://joxi.ru/Vrwb8VkfOQ6JnA

I need to follow this order, I do not quite understand how I can use it require.context  for this moment

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bundle them into one file, you can use next syntax in webpack.config.js:

```
{
  entry: [
    'path/to/file/1',
    'path/to/file/2',
    '...',
    'path/to/file/n',
  ]
}
```

For multiple entry points you are able to use next configuration:

```
{
    entry: {
        firstEntryPoint: [
            'path/to/entry/point/1/fist/file',
            'path/to/entry/point/1/second/file',
            '...',
        ],
        secondEntryPoint: [
            'path/to/entry/point/2/fist/file',
            'path/to/entry/point/2/second/file',
            '...',
        ],
        // ...
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        // ...
    }
}
```

As a result, webpack generates two files with names `firstEntryPoint.js` and `secondEntryPoint.js`.

More about webpack configuration object is described in [this doc](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/#options).

Comment: I have many pages, for each of them I want to collect 1 file in the correct queue, this option will work like this? how then to collect for each stria its file?